# How can I call functions in PHP depending of their position?

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops

I'm currently trying to build a sorting function for some div's in PHP. First I've put each section into one function so that when I call this function, the section get's printed.

Now I've the problem that I don't know how I can call each section depending on their position? This is my code:

```
    $elements = array(
        'section_one'   => 6,
        'section_two'   => 1,
        'section_three' => 0,
        'section_four'  => 3,
        'section_five'  => 2,
        'section_six'   => 5,
        'section_seven' => 4
    );

    foreach ( $elements as $element => $position ) {

    }

    get_section_one( $a, $b, $c );
    get_section_two( $a, $b, $c, $d );
    get_section_three( $a, $b );
    get_section_four( $a );
    get_section_five( $a, $b, $c, $d, $e );
    get_section_six( $a, $b, $c );
    get_section_seven( $a, $b, $c );
```

Each function has different parameters which are not defined. The `$elements` array has a key which is the name of the section and a value which defines the position.

So has anyone an idea how I can call each function depending on their position from the lowest number to the highest?

In my example `section_three` must be the first element which should be called...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For order you need to [sort your array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) (for now `asort()` is what you need), but before doing that I'd rework the array and make function position a key, not the value as you have now (assuming position is unique of course). Once sorted you can iterate using usual `foreach($elements as $func_name)` and the helper method you are looking for is [call_user_func()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

```
foreach ( $elements as $func_name ) {
    call_user_func($func_name, ....)
}
```

There's one issue though, that you have different number of arguments for each of these functions, so this may get tricky. You may want to rework your functions to accept i.e. array of arguments instead. This could be additionally beneficial, as arguments array could be ten part of your `$elements` array, so no additional "builder" logic would be needed, i.e.:

```php
$elements = [
  0 => [ 'name' => 'section_three',
         'args' => [$a, $b],
       ],
  ...
  2 => [ 'name' => 'get_section_five',
         'args' => [$a, $b, $c, $d, $e],
       ],
  ...
];

ksort($elements);

foreach($elements as $el) {
    call_user_func($el['name'], $el['args']);
}
```

Comment: Position is the order of each element on my website so 0 is the first, 1 the next and so on. And yes, I've multiple arguments which are different in each function. So any idea how to fix this and to get each function in the right order?

Comment: Now I've understand it. In my case I can't save the args in the array because this comes out of my database. My idea is to put everything in a switch and pass the args depending on the function to the call. Is this a good idea?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `asort()` to order the elements (keeping the keys of the array) right before your loop.

```
$elements = array(
    'section_one'   => 6,
    'section_two'   => 1,
    'section_three' => 0,
    'section_four'  => 3,
    'section_five'  => 2,
    'section_six'   => 5,
    'section_seven' => 4
);

asort($elements);

foreach ( $elements as $element => $position ) {

}
```

Comment: this is one way of doing it if you only have a few functions. What if you have 1000 function names? in the foreach you will do a huge switch or if/else statements? I think Marcin Orlowski's answer is much better than this one